# ext4 slow write performance after file system is 90% full

Tags: linux, performance, nfs, ubuntu-18.04, ext4

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.
My observation for ext4 file system is, once I cross the 90% of data usage the write performance crawls. 
We have a RAID6 configuration over 12 disks, total 90TB file system. For 81TB we experience 1400 MBps. Post that it drops down to 100 MBps. This drop is very sharp. Is there a way to make it less severe?

I'm exporting my ext4 volume as NFS share. To avoid write crawling after 90% usage, is there any way to force ENOSPACE error on NFS clients post filesystem crosses 90% usage.

Comment: Same here (though it more like the last 1%). I suspect this is due to fragmentation, there is no continuous space big enough so your files get scattered all over the disk and you get a lot or arm movements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the tune2fs -m to change the reserved blocks percentage.  The default is 5%; you can change it 15% or 20%.  Note that df subtracts out the reserved blocks.  So when you see "100%" in df, if the default reserved blocks is 5%, it's actually 95% full.   Root is allowed to use the reserved space; but non-root users will get ENOSPC when they try to write beyond "100%".   So for example, with the reserved blocks set to 25% (tune2fs -m 25 /tmp/foo.img), df will report:

```
% df -h /mnt
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0       27M   19M  2.0K 100% /mnt
```